# Целесообразность использования тулкита VLC

Tags: vlc, qt

Задача состоит в том, чтобы в приложении отображать содержимое нескольких видеопотоков. Очень важна возможность обработки H.264 потоков. Приложение пишется под Qt. Очень советуют использовать библиотеки VLC. Отпугивает громоздкость.
Кто-нибудь пользовался? Что скажите? Какие альтернативы посоветуете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве `LGPL` альтернатив существуют [**GStreamer**](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) и банальный [**ffmpeg**.](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)

Что из них менее громоздко и больше соответствует вашим нуждам - это, конечно же, субъективный выбор, но лично я бы остановился на `libvlc` - и документация радует, и коммьюнити разработчиков в разы больше.

Comment: Буду копать. Спасибо.